# How can i return "this" type in extended class

Tags: typescript

here is the code

```
abstract class Model {
  abstract fetch(): Partial<this>;
}

class X extends Model {
  public a = 1;

  fetch() {
    return { a: 2 };
  }
}
```

I'm trying to return a X type in X.fetch but i got this

```
Property 'fetch' in type 'X' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Model'.
  Type '() => { a: number; }' is not assignable to type '() => Partial<this>'.
    Type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<this>'.ts(2416)
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to refer to the extending class from abstract as you did with `Partial<this>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can move response data in a separate class and use it something like this:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
  abstract fetch(): any
}

class XDto{
    public a: number = 1
}
    
class XModel extends XDto implements BaseModel {
  fetch(): Partial<XDto> {
    return {a: 1};
  }
}


const x = new X()

const a = x.fetch()
```

Comment: that may can solve the problem, but I had to "implements" the baseModel and write DTO everywhere, I really want a "the write once run anywhere baseModel the silver bullet" to rescue my hands >.<